# Get current country shows null

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get current country name, city name and address line but it returns "NULL". When I send request for longitude and latitude, it returns correct longitude and latitude.

> country name =null ,city name = null,address line = null

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView latitude, longitude, country, city, postalCodeTV, addressLineTV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // check if GPS enabled
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

    if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation())
    {
        String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
        latitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldLatitude);
        latitude.setText("Latitude: "+stringLatitude);

        String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
        longitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldLongitude);
        longitude.setText("Longitude: "+stringLongitude);

        String countryVal = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
        country = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldCountry);
        country.setText("country: "+countryVal);
        System.out.println("pakistan  "+countryVal);

        String cityVal = gpsTracker.getLocality(this);
        city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldCity);
        city.setText("city: "+cityVal);

        String postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(this);
        postalCodeTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldPostalCode);
        postalCodeTV.setText("postalCode: "+postalCode);

        String addressLine = gpsTracker.getAddressLine(this);
        addressLineTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldAddressLine);
        addressLineTV.setText("addressLine: "+addressLine);

    }
    else
    {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
    }


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your device should be available to connect to internet. These values will be null if you have not an internet connection. You can control if you have internet or not with this function:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also add these permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these permission into your manifest

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and also turn ON Gps on your device/emulator